# A basic question on left and right eigen vector

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I see the following in a book: "Suppose $P$ is a stochastic matrix. the column vector with all $1$s is a right eigen vector with eigen value 1. Hence at least one left eigenvector for eigenvalue 1 exists."

How the last line follows from the first two line is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

$Av=v$ so $(A-I)v=0$ so $A-I$ is singular so there exists $w$ such that $w(A-I)=0$ which is $wA=w$.

Comment: is it possible to tell without determinant ? I am not aware of it.

Comment: Who said anything about determinants? A (square) matrix $M$ is singular if $Mx=0$ has a nonzero solution, which means that the columns of $M$ are linearly dependent, which means the rows of $M$ are linearly dependent (since the dimension of the column space equals the dimension of the row space), which implies $xM=0$ has a nonzero solution.

Comment: sorry, i thought singular is defined as zero determinant.

Comment: It can be defined that way. It can also be defined as non-invertible. There is a long list of equivalent properties, and you can take any one as the definition, and then prove the others as theorems, and different authors make different choices. In any event, with my comment you now have a proof that makes no reference to determinants.

Comment: Here "row rank equals column rank" is enough (which holds also for non-square matrices, where we do not even have determinants).

Comment: @Hagen, yes, but the question is about eigenvectors, so non-square matrices don't enter into the discussion. Also, for nonsquare matrices, it's no longer true that $Mx=0$ has a nonzero solution if and only if $xM=0$ has a nonzero solution, and I need that for the argument.